# Labels outside of plots

Tags: r, plot

I am hoping to add the labels "a)" and "b)" to my two plots so that I can differentiate and discuss them more effectively when writing up. Ive tried to do this through the text and legend functions but I'm not getting any good results. Ideally I would have the a) in the very top left of the ep.var.hist plot (1st plot) and the b) in the very top left of the tp.var.hist plot (2nd plot), with the labels sitting outside the actual plot and above the y-axis labels.
My code is below

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(4,4,0.9,4))
ep.var.hist<-hist(data.ep, breaks=5, xlim=c(0,0.011), ylim=c(0,6000), xlab=NULL, main=NULL)  
tp.var.hist<-hist(data.tp, breaks=66, xlim=c(0,0.011), ylim=c(0,6000), xlab="Variance", main=NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with the `cowplot` package, designed to ease the process for producing publication ready plots.

```
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)

sepal <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(text = element_text(margin = margin(), debug = FALSE))

petal <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(text = element_text(margin = margin(), debug = FALSE))

plot_grid(sepal, petal, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

`plot_grid` and `save_plot` (a polished version of `ggsave`) are my two favorite `cowplot` functions. I highly recommend looking at the help pages for more options and customization.

If you really want to keep it to just `graphics` try this solution, I think you are looking for `adj = 0`:

```
 par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(4,4,0.9,4))
 petal <- hist(iris$Petal.Length, main = "Petal", adj = 0)
 sepal <- hist(iris$Sepal.Length, main = "Sepal", adj = 0)
```

Full disclaimer I would strongly consider using `ggplot2` in the long term like @rosscova suggested. You will have a lot more options for controlling the details of your plots, plus lots of modern visualizations that base R just can't do. There is a reason why `ggplot2` is so popular :)

Comment: Im not currently plotting using ggplot. Is there another method to do this or will I need to go ahead and start plotting using ggplot?

Comment: If you do much plotting, I'd recommend getting to know ggplot, it'll be well worth your while.

Comment: @Will updated with a baseR solution that might be acceptable, albeit not as pretty

Comment: Yes! I got going with ggplot and now all is good. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I apologise, I went ahead and answered without realising you said "outside of plots", which I don't think my answer can achieve.

I don't know how to do this in base, but ggplot2 has the `annotate` function to achieve what you're after. Here's an example from which you can start playing (I've added a few bits you might want to help get you started):

```
library( ggplot2 )
plot <- ggplot( diamonds ) + 
    geom_histogram( aes( carat ), bins = 30 ) +
    annotate( "text", label = "label here", x = 1, y = 7500, col = "red" ) +
    annotate( "text", label = "and another", x = 2, y = 5500, col = "blue" )

plot <- plot + 
    xlim( 0, 3 ) + 
    ggtitle( "Main title" ) +
    xlab( "label x" ) + 
    ylab( "label y" )

plot
```

Adjust the `x` and `y` values within the `annotate` function to move the label around. You can add as many of these as you like by adding more calls to `annotate`.

Comment: Indeed. A vote for your answer then, well deserved :)